# What happened between Garak and Ziyal's grandfather?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Is there any further information than [this singular quote](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/494.htm)  about what Garak did to Ziyal's granddad? Or maybe more importantly how it was a significant enough and well-known act that even Major Kira knew about it and told Ziyal about it at some point?

> ZIYAL: You really think I asked you here to kill you? Well, it did occur to me. Kira and my father both told me that you used to be an agent of the Obsidian Order. **That you had my grandfather tortured and killed**, and that you could easily kill me without a second thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much the only (semi-canon) mention was a [noodle-incident](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident) involving an arms merchant, seen in a deleted scene from [DS9: The Die is Cast](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/467.txt)

> **TAIN:** (thinks) *Dukat...* ?
>
> **GARAK:** *He's the son of the late Justice Procal.*
>
> **TAIN:** *Oh, yes... **the business with the arms merchant.***
> (beat)
> *I take it, you'd like to have him eliminated...*

---

Moving further down the canon, Procal Dukat appears in several EU novels including [A Stitch in Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Stitch_in_Time). We learn that he was involved in a clandestine "brotherhood" of hard-line conservative Cardassians committed to returning Cardassia Prime to its former glories by systematically attacking the other Alpha Quadrant superpowers and by dominating and enslaving less-developed civilisations within its sphere of influence. Enabran Tain, as part of the supposedly liberal faction was one of those considered by the Brotherhood to be too soft and was scheduled for (ahem) replacement. Tain got there first and had his protegé, Elim Garak, drug Dukat's father (Ziyal's grandfather) and interrogate him. He gave up the existence of the Brotherhood but none of its names and was interrogated to death shortly afterwards.

> *“Did you go to Romulus?” he asked.*
> *“Yes, I did. With Barkan,” I added*.
> *“He’s good. He’s good, son,” the old man nodded. “But watch him. He’s like his father. If a better deal can be made. . . .” I modulated higher. He was seized by a spasm and his face contorted into a rictus. “That’s what they look like!” he screamed. “That’s what they really look like when you strip away. . . .” His breath ran out and he began to choke in an attempt to refill his lungs. I chose not to modulate down. **“We have to . . . kill them. Carriers . . . they carry the disease. Every one of them. Surround the Assembly . . . let everyone watch so they never forget. Ghemor . . . Lang . . . the guls who stand with them . . . especially the traitors!”** Dukat was energized and tried to rise as if he were exhorting his troops. The frustration of not being able to poured into his words.
> **“The Brotherhood has to move now! The families must take their rightful place. Support the Directorate or die. And no exile! Exile is just deferred treachery. Those who were meant to rule must rule.** End these negotiations with the Federation. Use the Romulans to drive the wedge! What did they say?” he suddenly asked me. “Will they move with us against the Klingons?”*

Obviously this conflicts slightly with the description from the deleted scene, but this is pretty common when dealing with such a peripheral character. No explanation is given for how Major Kira knows about it.

Comment: I’m not following

Comment: A 'noodle-incident' is something that's alluded to but not actually discussed in sufficient detail for the audience to glean anything other than the outline. *"You remember that time in Paris with the thing?"*, *"It's not going to turn out like Morocco is it?"*, etc.

Comment: Mandatory TV tropes link (WARNUNGm TV Tropes link): https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident